# error: non-aggregate type 'Point' (aka 'Point_<int>') cannot be initialized with an initializer list

Tags: android, c++

I'm using c++ in Android Studio. However, when I run the code below :

```
int GetAngleABC(Point a, Point b, Point c) 
{
Point ab = { b.x - a.x, b.y - a.y };
Point cb = { b.x - c.x, b.y - c.y };

float dot = (ab.x * cb.x + ab.y * cb.y); // dot product
float cross = (ab.x * cb.y - ab.y * cb.x); // cross product

float alpha = atan2(cross, dot);

return (int)floor(alpha * 180.0 / CV_PI + 0.5);
}
```

The Studio output error message :

> Error:(30, 11) error: non-aggregate type 'Point' (aka 'Point_') cannot be initialized with an initializer list

And the error spots is :

> Point ab = { b.x - a.x, b.y - a.y };
>     Point cb = { b.x - c.x, b.y - c.y };

Comment: Enable `-std=c++11`.